# PushNotification is not working In ng-Cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

We are using below code in controller.we follow steps below:

1)We are getting Sender Id from `GCM` while  project creation

2)Sending  Sender ID  to `GCM` Server  like this the

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
.controller('notificationCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaPush,$rootScope) {
var androidConfig = {
    "senderID": "293702747276",
  };
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
$cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
      // Success
      alert(result);
    }, function(err) {
      // Error
    })

    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
      alert(event);

       alert('notification' + notification);

      switch(notification.event) {


        case 'registered':
          if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
            alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
            console.log('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
          }
          break;

        case 'message':
          // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
          alert('message = ' + notification.message + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
          break;

        case 'error':
          alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
          break;

        default:
          alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
          break;
      }
    });

    // WARNING: dangerous to unregister (results in loss of tokenID)
    $cordovaPush.unregister(options).then(function(result) {
      // Success!
    }, function(err) {
      // Error
    })

  }, false);
            })
`
```

3) Now Getting Registration ID From `GCM`

4)Then Registration Id Hit local server hit in to Browser the response getting Success But `PushNotification` is not getting in Mobile

Please guide us.Tell me whats wrong in my code. We are developing `ng-Cordova` Mobile Application